# How to change the Network name shown in Windows's ncpa.cpl using C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, networking

Windows' **"Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"** dialog (also by running **ncpa.cpl**) is used to show the Networks. A user can rename the name of Network by right-clicking and choosing "rename". This name is different with the **adapter name**, for instance, my ethernet card has the **Network name** being **"Ethernet"**, but with the **adapter name** called **"Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)"**. I know I can change the latter one using NetCfg API, **but I don't know how to change the former one, the "Ethernet"**.

I know that **netsh** command seems to do this work. But I want to **implement this renaming using C++**. Is there a way?

---

**SOLUTION:**

I'm so happy that got problem **SOLVED** using **NetShareManager API**! **NETCON_PROPERTIES** structure saves the **GUID** of the device, used to search the device, **INetConnection::Rename** can be used to rename the **Network Connection** name!

Here's the code:

```
BOOL DoTheWork(INetSharingManager *pNSM, wchar_t strDeviceName[])
{   // add a port mapping to every firewalled or shared connection 
    BOOL bFound = FALSE;
    INetSharingEveryConnectionCollection * pNSECC = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = pNSM->get_EnumEveryConnection (&pNSECC);
    if (!pNSECC)
        wprintf (L"failed to get EveryConnectionCollection!\r\n");
    else {

        // enumerate connections
        IEnumVARIANT * pEV = NULL;
        IUnknown * pUnk = NULL;
        hr = pNSECC->get__NewEnum (&pUnk);
        if (pUnk) {
            hr = pUnk->QueryInterface (__uuidof(IEnumVARIANT),
                (void**)&pEV);
            pUnk->Release();
        }
        if (pEV) {
            VARIANT v;
            VariantInit (&v);

            while ((S_OK == pEV->Next (1, &v, NULL)) && (bFound == FALSE)) {
                if (V_VT (&v) == VT_UNKNOWN) {
                    INetConnection * pNC = NULL;
                    V_UNKNOWN (&v)->QueryInterface (__uuidof(INetConnection),
                        (void**)&pNC);
                    if (pNC) {
                        NETCON_PROPERTIES *pNETCON_PROPERTIES;
                        pNC->GetProperties(&pNETCON_PROPERTIES);

                        wchar_t currentGUID[BUF_SIZE];
                        GUID guid = pNETCON_PROPERTIES->guidId;
                        wsprintf(currentGUID, L"{%08X-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X}", 
                            guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, 
                            guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],
                            guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);

                        if (wcscmp(currentGUID, strDeviceName) == 0)
                        {
                            pNC->Rename(NPCAP_LOOPBACK_INTERFACE_NAME);
                            bFound = TRUE;
                        }

                        pNC->Release();
                    }
                }
                VariantClear(&v);
            }
            pEV->Release();
        }
        pNSECC->Release();
    }

    return bFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory look at the code for

```
netsh interface set interface name "oldname" newname="newname"
```

It looks to be using [INetworkConnection::Rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365099(v=vs.85).aspx). In order to get the connection you want, I believe you would have to use the [INetSharingManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365960(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate all the connections available. Then you would have to iterate through them to find the one you want and then call the Rename function.

All that being said, as @Alexander Balabin said, the NLM API would probably be easier, but I don't know for sure if it does what you want. I can just tell you what netsh does.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but [NLM API's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370799(v=vs.85).aspx) `INetwork` has a `SetName` method which looks like it should do what you want.

Comment: I am afraid that NLM API is not what I want, see updates.